# Does Sonar 3.7.1 still support the fb-contrib plugin?

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs

I'm looking into upgrading Sonar, from 3.2.1 to 3.7.1. In our current system, we have the fb-contrib plugin installed and many of its violations enabled. However, in the latest version, I do not see it listed in Update Center -> Available Plugins. I've looked at the release notes for each release and I do not seen any mention of fb-contrib. I've looked at the plugins homepage and it isn't clear. Does anyone know if it is still supported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not compatible with version 3.7. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+version+matrix

Comment: why is that? is there anywhere that says what the problem is? I will fix it.

Comment: I missed that compatibility matrix somehow. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: You can discuss it on the developer mailing list. See http://www.sonarqube.org/resources/join-our-community/

Comment: Update: The issue seems to be fixed now starting from sonar version 3.6:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+version+matrix